# json stringify in IE 8 gives run time error Object property or method not supported

Tags: json, internet-explorer-8, stringify

/* Problem description-     I am using json stringify method to convert an javascript array to string in json notation.However I get an error message that 'Object property or method not supported' at line 
    hidden.value = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    This should work as stringify is supported in IE8.Please advise

```
Full code below  */    
function getgridvalue() {

        var exportLicenseId;
        var bolGrossQuantity;
        var bolNetQuantity;
        var totalBolGrossQty =0 ;
        var totalBolNetQty =0;
        var jsonObj = []; //declare array
            var netQtyTextBoxValue = Number(document.getElementById("<%= txtNetQty.ClientID %>").value);
        var atLeastOneChecked = false;

        var gridview = document.getElementById("<%= ExporterGrid.ClientID %>"); //Grab a reference to the Grid

        for (i = 1; i < gridview.rows.length; i++) //Iterate through the rows
        {

            if (gridview.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0] != null && gridview.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type == "checkbox")
            {

                if (gridview.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked)
                {

                    atLeastOneChecked = true;
                    exportLicenseId = gridview.rows[i].cells[8].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    bolNetQuantity = gridview.rows[i].cells[5].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

                    if (bolNetQuantity == "") {
                        alert('<%= NetQuantityMandatory %>');
                        return false;
                        }
                    if (!isNumber(bolNetQuantity)) {
                        alert('<%= NetQuantityNumber %>');
                        return false;
                    }

                    totalBolNetQty += Number(bolNetQuantity);
                    jsonObj.push({ ExportLicenseId: Number(exportLicenseId),  BolNetQuantity: Number(bolNetQuantity) });

                }

            }
        }
if (gridview.rows.length > 2 && !atLeastOneChecked)
{
    alert('<%= SelectMsg %>');
                        return false;
                    }



if (totalBolNetQty != 0 && netQtyTextBoxValue != totalBolNetQty)
            {
                alert('<%= NetQuantitySum %>');
                return false;
            }

        var hidden = document.getElementById('HTMLHiddenField');
//        if (!this.JSON) {
//            this.JSON = {};
//        }
        var JSON = JSON || {};
        if (hidden != null) {

            hidden.value = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500) to check the browser mode. The JSON object exists, but has no methods in IE7 mode. Use the json2 library as a fallback.

- [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)